# How to implement fisherface algorithm and how much time will it take?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, facial-recognition

I found on the web that fisherface is the best algorithm for face detection. Before investing deeply into it, I just want to know how hard is it to implement it and how much time will it take.

I am new to this website and I welcome any suggestions.